# Prove for $\sigma \in S_n$, $\sigma(a_1, … , a_n)\sigma^{-1}= (\sigma(a_1),…, \sigma(a_n))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

How do I even begin this problem? Does it involve induction or something like induction?

Would it be more helpful to instead prove it as $$\sigma(a_1,..., a_n) = (\sigma(a_1),...,\sigma(a_m))\sigma\ ?$$ 
I'm lost.

Comment: See Theorem 5.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/conjclass.pdf).

Comment: It would be equivalent to show that $\sigma(a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n) = (\sigma(a_1), \sigma(a_2), \sigma(a_3),...\sigma(a_m))\sigma$, but I don't think that makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that for any $i$,
$$
[\sigma(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n) \sigma^{-1}](\sigma(a_i)) = \sigma(a_{i+1})
$$
where the indices $i$ are taken modulo $n$. No need for induction, just plug in and simplify.